# Bazel shared library does not include all symbols

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling, bazel, mediapipe

I am trying to build a shared library using bazel (mediapipe) and linking dependencies without sources or headers fails to include the dependency symbols.

Here is sorta psudo code example

```
cc_binary(
    name = "library.so",
    deps = ["//project:dependency"],
    linkshared = 1,
)
```

Some other file:

```
cc_library(
   name = "dependency",
   srcs = ["file.cc"],
   hdrs = ["file.h"]
)
```

in file.h

```
class MyClass {
public:
   int abc = 0;
};
```

Then when I build with Android let's say

```
bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm project:framework.so --linkopt="-s"
```

After I build, the shared library does not contain any symbols from file.h (MyClass) using

```
nm -D output/framework.so | grep MyClass
```

Is there a way to do it? I am also new to bazel.

A more defined question is located on mediapipe's issues page.

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix linkers traditionally drop symbols that are not required by the top-level target (i.e., code in `"library.so"` `cc_binary`). Bazel will ask the linker to forcefully include all code in a `cc_library` rule in the final top-level link if `alwayslink = True` is set on it.

Comment: Looks like i will need to add alwayslink to a lot of places, unless there is a way for the cc_binary to force all the dependencies to be included in the shared library?

Comment: There is a legacy mechanism to do that but `alwayslink` is preferred: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--legacy_whole_archive